# Why does Rust disallow "let v = Vec<i32>::new();"?

Tags: generics, rust

I feel `Vec::<i32>::new()` is not consistent with `Vec<i32>`

```
let v = Vec<i32>::new(); // cannot compile

let v1 : Vec<i32> = Vec::new(); // auto inference type parameters
let v2 = Vec::<i32>::new(); // quite weird
```

Comment: Is there a question here or did you come to lodge a complaint? While I agree that the turbofish looks a bit weird, it is what Rust has.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b99bd8f8be49ba9676d3274fdbd06b2d476adfcd/src/test/ui/bastion-of-the-turbofish.rs#L40-L43) for an example of the ambiguity avoided by the additional `::`.

Comment: @Kendas I guessed the reason is parsing issue, but could not confirm it. I'm here to find out whether there are other deeper reasons

Comment: Thanks to Rust’s type inference, you often don’t even need to specify the type of the vector’s elements. For instance, if you push something onto a vector whose generic type is unspecified, Rust will work backwards and deduce that it must be the type of the pushed element.

Answer (score 7):

The notation is affectionately called the turbofish.

`Vec<i32>::new()` presents a trade-off when parsing. Is the `<` introducing the generic argument, or is it a less than operator? To tell the difference requires potentially unbounded look-ahead. The turbofish avoids that.

That is not universally viewed as important. It has been proposed to allow `Vec<i32>::new()`, but the proposal was abandoned. See [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26040390).

That said, specifying the type parameter is less commonly needed than in comparable languages due to type inference as you noted in your second line.